# Android Studio Error:(386, 38) error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Context

Tags: java, android

When I attempt to compile my project in Android Studio, I get the following error:

```
Error:(386, 38) error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Context

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

The error refers to the line

```java
stripe = new Stripe(Const.STRIPE_TOKEN);
```

which exists in my `SummaryFragment.java` class:

```java
package com.example.Fragments;

// Stripe imports
import com.stripe.android.Stripe;
import com.stripe.android.TokenCallback;
import com.stripe.android.exception.AuthenticationException;
import com.stripe.android.model.Card;
import com.stripe.android.model.Token;

// Non-Stripe imports omitted

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class SummaryFragment extends Fragment implements 
    View.OnClickListener {

    // Other fields and methods omitted

    private void getStripeToken(String cardNo, String expMonth, String expYear, String cvv) {
        loadingDialog.show();
        Card card = new Card(cardNo, Integer.parseInt(expMonth), Integer.parseInt(expYear), cvv);
        Stripe stripe = null;

        try {
            stripe = new Stripe(Const.STRIPE_TOKEN);
            // Other logic omitted
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
new Stripe(Const.STRIPE_TOKEN);
```

To:

```
new Stripe(getActivity(), Const.STRIPE_TOKEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates, the [`Stripe` constructor you are attempting to use](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/blob/master/stripe/src/main/java/com/stripe/android/Stripe.java#L132) accepts a `Context`, not a `String`:

```
/**
 * A constructor with only context, to set the key later.
 *
 * @param context {@link Context} for resolving resources
 */
public Stripe(@NonNull Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}
```

If your `Const.STRIPE_TOKEN` is what I think it is, you may have more success using [the two-argument constructor](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/blob/master/stripe/src/main/java/com/stripe/android/Stripe.java#L142) that accepts both a `Context` and a `String` 'key':

```
/**
 * Constructor with publishable key.
 *
 * @param context {@link Context} for resolving resources
 * @param publishableKey the client's publishable key
 */
public Stripe(@NonNull Context context, String publishableKey) {
    mContext = context;
    setDefaultPublishableKey(publishableKey);
}
```

To do this you would replace the line

```
stripe = new Stripe(Const.STRIPE_TOKEN);
```

with the line

```
stripe = new Stripe(getActivity(), Const.STRIPE_TOKEN);
```

However, you should verify my assumption regarding the purpose of that token before proceeding.

Comment: thank you stkent for formatting my original question and making it more intelligent. when i try your recommendation, i get another error: Error:(405, 11) error: exception AuthenticationException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement. This error is pointing to line 405 and here is what's on line 405: } catch (AuthenticationException e) {

Comment: You're welcome! The new error is telling you that none of the code contained within the associated `try` block actually throws an `Exception` of type `AuthenticationException`. You might just be able to remove the catch block altogether. However, if that doesn't work, please post a new question that contains a small snippet of the relevant code. Since this answer appears to have successfully resolved the original issue, please mark it accepted (green check mark). By making sure each question focuses on exactly one issue, we make it easier for others to find answers later!